# Thumbnails not clickable after reloading via AJAX

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQZoom (plugin, version 2.3) for our product's photo galleries.  On the product page, the user has the option of selecting different attributes within a product which reloads images based on the selected attribute.  The user is able to click the thumbnails just fine on the initial page load but, when they select an attribute, the photos refresh via AJAX and the thumbnail images are no longer clickable.  Here's some code I'm working with:

This portion is called on page load and when a new product attribute is selected:

```
function findProductPhotos(attributeDetailID) {
    if( typeof attributeDetailID != "undefined" && attributeDetailID > 0 ) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            data: {
                method: 'getAttributeDetailImages',
                productAttributeDetailID: attributeDetailID
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                updateProductPhotos(data);
            },
            traditional: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "/com/ei/image/ImageProxy.cfc"
        });
    }
}
```

This function is called after the images are retrieved:

```
function updateProductPhotos(data) {
    // if images where returned, then update the main photo and thumbnail
        if(data.length > 0) {
            // remove all existence of jqzoom so we can reassign it correctly w/o error
            $(".jqzoom").unbind().removeData('jqzoom').empty();
            $(".zoomPad").remove();

            // remove all the current thumbnails
            $('#thumblist').empty();

            // put back all the new thumbnails and main product image
            $(data).each(function(i,objImg) {
                // if this is the first image, replace the main image with it
                if (i==0) {
                    var mainProdImgElem = $('<img id="mainProdImg" width="350" />');
                    $(mainProdImgElem).attr('src',objImg.srcHiRes);
                    $(mainProdImgElem).appendTo('.jqzoom');
                    $('.jqzoom').attr('href',objImg.srcHiRes);
                    $('.zoomWrapperImage').find('img').attr('src', objImg.srcHiRes);
                }

                var elemThumb = $('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="75" border="0" /></a></li>');
                if (i==0) {
                    $(elemThumb).find('a').addClass('zoomThumbActive');
                }
                $(elemThumb).find('img')
                    .attr('src', objImg.srcThumb)
                    .attr('rel', '{gallery: \'gal1\', smallimage: \'' + objImg.srcHiRes + '\', largeimage: \'' + objImg.srcHiRes + '\'}');
                $(elemThumb).appendTo('#thumblist');
            });

            // rebind jqzoom
            $(".jqzoom").jqzoom(jqZoomOptions);
        }
    }
```

And the HTML code snippet containing the thumbnails:

```
<ul class="clearfix" id="thumblist">
    <cfloop query="qimages">
        <cfset variables.Thumbnail = imageObj.getImageSrc(
                imageID = imageID,
                size = "thumbnail")>

        <cfif FileExists(ExpandPath(hiresFilename))>
            <cfset zoomerFile = hiresFilename />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset zoomerFile = largeFilename />
        </cfif>

        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" <cfif currentrow eq 1>class="zoomThumbActive" rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: '#zoomerFile#', largeimage: '#zoomerFile#'}">
                <img src="#variables.Thumbnail#" width="75" border="0">
            </a>
        </li>
    </cfloop>
</ul>
```

Any idea why this would happen or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation to bind your event handlers:

```
$(document).delegate('.my-images', 'click', eventHandler);
```

http://api.jquery.com/delegate

-- Another idea --

Instead of:

```
$(".jqzoom").unbind().removeData('jqzoom').empty();
```

How about:

```
$(".jqzoom").replaceWith('<div />', { class : 'jqzoom' });
```

Just replace the `.jqzoom` element(s) rather than unbinding and removing data/html.

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith

Answer (score 0):

**just by reading the title**, it seems like you are running into dynamic content insertion problems, the thing is event handler do not attach themselves to the dynamically added elements to the DOM either re-attach the event handler in the `ajax` success handler like

```
success:function(data){

 $("Element").bind("click");
}
```

or use event delegation using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method

```
$(document).delegate("ELEMENT","click",function(e){
 //event handler code here
});
```

if you are using the jquery version 1.7+ use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method

```
$(document).on("click","ELEMENTselector",function(e){
 //event handler code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help everyone.  Your solutions work fine but, after looking into it further, the real problem was the "rel" attribute being loading into the  tag instead of the  tag in jQuery.  Again, appreciate your help.